# AlertDialog how to handle click outside of dialog view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have `AlertDialog` and there are some buttons. By clicking them, some function/method begin to work.

But what to do if user clicks outside of AlertDialog view?

I want to start specific function then user clicks at empty field (outside of dialog view)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use this -

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Then for executing your function on outside click of dialog, do like this -

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // dialog dismisses
        // Do your function here
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you help me, what if I want to do my function and only then dismiss my dialog. how can I do it? I suppose I have to owerwrite dismiss function, but as I am new developer, I am not sure how can I do it correctly

Comment: Set dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); initially

Comment: Then call the same  dialog.setOnCancelListener,  inside that you will call the function you want to execute,  in the success or failure of that method,  call dialog.dismiss()

Comment: unfortunately this solution do not work because when dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) function dialog.setOnCancelListener does not start in this case, I just tried to do that :(

Comment: You should have mentioned this requirement in your question itself

Comment: sorry, I thought solution will be easy :( I will accept you answer but if you could help me with this problem, it would be very nice  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195872/discussion-between-zachary-and-pavel-malinovskij).

Comment: I am on it.  Give me some time please

Comment: Just try dialog.show()  inside on cancel and then call dismiss after the function